# generate random letter and fixed number combination

Tags: random, rust

I need to generate a random sequence of a single letter and 6 digit combination, example: `F841257`

I was looking into `rand` crate, but something doesn't quite work.

```
extern crate rand;

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", rand::random::<char>());
}
```

prints something like `'\u{6ae02}'` and `println!("{}", rand::random::<char>());` produces some weird glyph.

Can someone point me in the right direction of how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, a working program:

```rust
extern crate rand;

use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let letter: char = rng.gen_range(b'A', b'Z') as char;
    let number: u32 = rng.gen_range(0, 999999);
    let s = format!("{}{:06}", letter, number);
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

Next, an explanation.

`rand::random::<char>()` returns a random value from the whole `char` range, that is, it may return arbitrary Unicode code point. That's why you see weird glyphs - these are likely values from upper Unicode planes.

You need to define boundaries of what you need to generate. First, you need a letter, then you need six digits. A letter is any character between 'A' and 'Z', and six digits can be represented by a number from 0 to 999999 which is padded with zeros when printing.

So, first, we generate a `u8` which corresponds to a letter in ASCII and convert it to `char` (unfortunately, `rand` crate does not provide range distribution for `char`s, so we have to use such indirection).

Second, we generate a `u32` between 0 and 999999.

Then we print them in the desired format. Here are a few values which this program generates: V285490, Y865809, A704620.

Comment: Perhaps the reason that no range distribution is provided for `char` is that code points U+D800 to u+DFFF (which correspond to the surrogates) are not valid.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rand/rand/trait.Rng.html#method.gen_range), `gen_range` generates in the range [low, high), so not including high. How would I change the code to make Z999999 an option?

Comment: @Sebastian, `rng.gen_range(0, 1000000)`?

Comment: That would work. And `rng.gen_range(b'A', b'Z'+1) as char` for the letter. I think a function with an inclusive range [low, high] would be nice to have...